# Extract substrings from a string

Tags: c#

I have string variable that has value like this

```
string hello = "Endpoint: Efficacy, Intervene: Single Group, Mask: Open, Purpose: Treatment";
```

As I am extracting from XML so `Endpoint` , `Intervene` , `Mask` and `Purpose` remains
same but its value can change.
I want to store this `Endpoint` , `intervene` , `mask` and `purpose` separately in  different variables any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You shoudl deserialize your XML to an object wich matches your variables.

Comment: @MarcelTheis He should still parse that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your `string` first by `,` and then by `:` and save the result in dictionary:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string hello = "Endpoint: Efficacy, Intervene: Single Group, Mask: Open, Purpose: Treatment";
        string[] arr = hello.Split(',');
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach(string s in arr)
        {
            string[] keyValuePair = s.Split(':');
            result[keyValuePair[0].Replace(" ","")] = keyValuePair[1].Replace(" ","");

        }

        foreach(var v in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.Key + " : " + v.Value );
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using `Dictionary`

```
        string hello = "Endpoint: Efficacy, Intervene: Single Group, Mask: Open, Purpose: Treatment";
        Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var s1 = hello.Split(',');

        foreach (var s in s1)
        {
            var v = s.Split(':');
            result.Add(v[0].Trim(), v[1].Trim());
        }
```

After that you can get result using `key` `value` of the `Dictionary`

```
        foreach (var a in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Key +" " + a.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = hello.Split(',')
               .Select(part => part.Split(':'))
               .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1].Trim());
```

Comment: could add trim on the key as well while being there. there is an extra space in front in the subsequent items. But this is the cleanest, readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is fixed, this can help you.

```
string hello = "Endpoint: Efficacy, Intervene: Single Group, Mask: Open, Purpose: Treatment";
string[] packs = hello.Split(',');
var data = packs.ToDictionary(k => k.Split(':').First().Trim(), v => v.Split(':').Last().Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something more dynamic just in case someone have to deal with variable keywords to match.

This first extracts the keywords and builds a pattern to match. Matches are then captured by name and each capture group is named after a keyword so that we can access them by keyword:

```
var input = "Endpoint: Efficacy, Intervene: Single Group, Mask: Open, Purpose: Treatment";

//extract keywords: (word followed by ':' )
var keywords = Regex.Matches( input, @"(\w*):" ).Cast<Match>()
    .Select( m => m.Groups[ 1 ].Value );

//build the pattern to match (create capture groups named as keywords)
var pattern = String.Join( ", ", keywords.Select( 
    k => k + $@": (?<{k}>(\w*\s*)*)" ) );

var matches = Regex.Matches( input, pattern );

//access groups by keyword
foreach( var keyword in keywords )
    Console.WriteLine( matches[ 0 ].Groups[ keyword ].Value );
```